# How can I connect a keyboard when the connector appears broken?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, thinkpad, laptop-repair

I have been working on a Lenovo ThinkPad X121e with the goal of replacing the keyboard. I have been replacing it using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kxSeAs1aEk4), But at the point where I am to plug in the cable to connect the keyboard, these small clips don't appear to be on the motherboard:
[image: Missing black connectors]
For comparison, here is the larger connecting unit on my laptop, the black connecting clip (used to secure the keyboard) is missing:
[image]
Is there any way I can fix this, or can I now not connect a keyboard to the laptop's motherboard?

PS: Can these clips/connecting switches be bought anywhere?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski I added a picture comparing my laptop to the one in the tutorial

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski yes that is the situation